# What is the correct way to post a username collected from a user, to an existing API endpoint?

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS what is the correct way to post a username collected from a user to a controller?

Do I use a function or a form, I don't want the controller to be fired on page load as I want to collect the username before applying the controller.

So I need to know how to activate the controller from the form.

The API itself works fine i've tested with postman I post in the url a username and it returns the correct json.

Comment: see this: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Comment: Unless initializing the controller you cant call any functions in the respective controller. Or if you have any parent controller,then you can use some flag to initialize the controller.

Comment: You need a form for user to input name and a controller for that form. Question really doesn't make sense

Comment: Use a service to share data across various controllers/components in app

Comment: Thankyou @Groben that looks interesting could be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thankyou @charlietfl there seem to be a number of ways to do it, Im a bit of a novice so it can be confusing, I was just wondering how a pro would do it as I want to learn the right way. Every angular tutorial Ive come across teaches a different approach.

Comment: depends a lot on the process flow needed

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms). Also look at the [ng-submit directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit).